# Databricks: Difference between dbfs:/ vs file:/

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, aws-databricks

I am trying to understand the way Databricks stores files and I am a bit unsure of what the difference is between **dbfs:/** and **file:/** (see image below)

[image]

From what I have been able to deduce from [here](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/7518333740958534/244803751991624/7702634641398412/latest.html?_ga=2.125187658.1510666795.1598516972-162714723.1598002453), file:/ seems to be the area where external files downloaded via curl/wget get downloaded into in the following folder path:

```
%fs ls "file:/databricks/driver"
```

But what is **file:/** really and why does it exist and how is it different from **dbfs:/**?

For the record, I am using the community free edition of Databricks.

Comment: local filesystem for file and databricks filesystem for dbfs

Comment: @Lamanus Appreciate the response! Could you clarify what is meant by local filesystem or where I could read up more about it?

Comment: You should know about hadoop and how to access to the distributed filesystem.

Comment: @Lamanus Yes, I have no issues understanding hadoop or DBFS as there is sufficient documentation available. What has stumped me is how and why the local filesystem exists in addition to the distributed file system.

Comment: distributed filrsystem is somehow logical and it is installed by a software on the physical local fs.

Comment: @Lamanus Thank you for the response! By physical local fs, do you mean my personal computer/mac or a remote computer where databricks is installed perhaps? Because the folders listed by file:/ are definitely not on my system.

Comment: yeap that is the remote one.

Comment: It is not related so programming. Try asking at https://unix.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: `file:/` is the local filesystem on the driver node of the (remote) cluster you are working on, `dbfs:/` is an evolution of `hdfs`, but that's historical and not really relevant here. Don't use `file:` for your working data or code. 2023 update: Databricks now has Unity Catalog and `volumes` which are external locations that point to s3 (or `adfs` or `gs` if you're using databricks on Azure or GCP), so we should move away from using dbfs and use volumes instead..