# Unable to access file from DBFS using DataBricks fuse mount path

Tags: databricks, databricks-community-edition

I have files in data bricks as shown below
[image]

I am trying to access them like this from data bricks notebooks
[image]

But I am getting error, even trying to use `pandas` gives an error
[image]

I don't understand where am I going wrong. Althought `dbutils.fs.head('/FileStore/tables/flights_small.csv')` gives me result correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using DataBricks **Community Edition**, because of a [quirk with DBR >= 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68948979/4829158), you cannot read in from your path.

I usually just have a command like the new one below to resolve this issue and programmatically bring te file to the accessible temp folder:

```
%fs cp /FileStore/tables/flights_small.csv file:/tmp/flights_small.csv
```

then simply read it in:

```py
pd.read_csv('file:/tmp/flights_small.csv')
```

---

Given quirks like this in the Community Edition (long cluster startup times), I usually go with [Google Colab](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/) for hobby work in a browser notebook.

Also you can run pyspark on Google Colab with just

```py
!pip install pyspark

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder\
        .master("local")\
        .appName("Colab")\
        .config('spark.ui.port', '4050')\
        .getOrCreate()
```

Comment: Oh I see, actually, I am exploring great expectations with spark, don't want to insrtall spark cluster. One clarification I want, what is the difference between `dbfs:` and `file:`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63667523/databricks-difference-between-dbfs-vs-file is a great answer. 

Source: Google `dbfs vs file databricks`